# move base velocity commands

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: switching from amcl to gmapping has no effect of current goal. The global path is direct to the goal but the current path to the  goal is over over the place. Also turning off DWA had no effect.

Update: Here is a video of the odd behavor , note that the global path is fine but the local path can not be determined.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/107473518@N08/10625510473/

Update: Here are my setting I use for costmap and amcl. Can anyone see somthing in the setting to prevent the local plan.

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  # for details see: http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner
  controller_frequency: 20
  escape_vel:           0.1  # no backing up

  max_vel_x: .2
  max_trans_vel: .2
  min_vel_x: 0.05
  min_trans_vel: 0..05
  max_rotational_vel: 0.1   # 0.1 rad/sec = 5.7 degree/sec
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.05

  acc_lim_th: 0.05
  acc_lim_x:  0.05
  acc_lim_y:  0

  holonomic_robot: false

  # goal tolerance parameters
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.5
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.5
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true

  # Forward Simulation Paramet
  sim_time: 100.0                  # The amount of time to forward-simulate trajectories in seconds
  sim_granularity: 0.02            # The step size, in meters, to take between points on a given trajectory
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.02    # The step size, in radians, to take between angular samples on a given trajectory.
  vx_samples: 20                   # The number of samples to use when exploring the x velocity space
  vtheta_samples: 20               # The number of samples to use when exploring the theta velocity space


  # Trajectory Scoring Parameters
  meter_scoring: true              # If true, distances are expressed in meters; otherwise grid cells
  #path_distance_bias: 32.2        # The weighting for how much the controller should stay close to the path it was given
  #goal_distance_bias: 22.4        # The weighting for how much the controller should attempt to reach its local goal, also controls speed
  occdist_scale: 0.1              # The weighting for how much the controller should attempt to avoid obstacles

  publish_cost_grid: true 
  prune_plan: false
```

common costmap.yaml

```
obstacle_range:         2.5
raytrace_range:         3.0
footprint:              [[0.25, 0.1], [0.25, -0.1], [-0.25,-0.1], [-0.25, 0.1]]  
max_scaling_factor:     0.02  # The scalling factor for footprint defined in local costmap
inflation_radius:       0.02 # Propagating cost values out from occupied cells that decrease with distance.
map_type:               costmap
track_unknown_space:    true
observation_sources:    laser_scan_sensor 
laser_scan_sensor:      {sensor_frame: hokuyo_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
resolution:             0.005



global_costmap:
  global_frame:        /map
  robot_base_frame:    /base_link
  update_frequency:    30.0
  publish_frequency:   30.0
  static_map:          true
  width:               20.0
  height:              20.0
  origin_x:            -10.0
  origin_y:            -10.0



local_costmap:
  global_frame:      /odom
  robot_base_frame:  /base_link
  update_frequency:  10.0
  publish_frequency: 10.0
  static_map:        false
  rolling_window:    true
  width:             16.0
  height:            16.0
  origin_x:          -8.0
  origin_y:          -8.0



amcl: 
   # Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
     odom_model_type :      "diff" 
     odom_alpha5 :          "0.1" 
     gui_publish_rate :     "30.0" 
     laser_max_beams :      "60" 
     laser_max_range :      "12.0" 
     min_particles :        "500" 
     max_particles :        "2000" 
     kld_err :              "0.05" 
     kld_z :                "0.99" 
     odom_alpha1 :          "0.2" 
     odom_alpha2 :          "0.2" 
     # translation std dev, m -->
     odom_alpha3 :          "0.2" 
     odom_alpha4 :          "0.2" 
     laser_z_hit :          "0.5" 
     laser_z_short :        "0.05" 
     laser_z_max :          "0.05" 
     laser_z_rand :         "0.5" 
     laser_sigma_hit :      "0.2" 
     laser_lambda_short :   "0.1" 
     laser_model_type :     "likelihood_field" 
     #  laser_model_type :   "beam"  -->
     laser_likelihood_max_dist :   "2.0" 
     update_min_d :         "0.25" 
     update_min_a :         "0.2" 
     resample_interval :    "1" 
     # Increase tolerance because the computer can get quite busy -->
     transform_tolerance :  "1.0" 
     recovery_alpha_slow :  "0.0" 
     recovery_alpha_fast :  "0.0"
```

Update: move_base goes directly into recovery but there is no obstacle near the robot. Why would this happen , what would case move_base to use escape_vel.

Update: If I have rear wheels that extend outside the robot footprint , they are in back out of sight of the scanner , will this cause problems in path planning?

Update: By setting the escape_vel to a none negative number. The robot stop moving backward proving that in fact it was in a recovery mode. Now if only I can figure out why? Here is a pic of rviz.

[image: image description]

I checked the log files but did not see any output related to recovery behaviors.

I was having problems with my robot following move base velocity commands as it tries to follow the local path. I could not see what was wrong so I hooked it up to turtlebot teleop keyboard. The robot followed the keyboard signals correctly. But when I set a simple goal in rivz move_base sends negative values to causing the robot to move backwards in both gazebo and rivz. Why is this? Where should I look. It I am to believe the keyboard controller there is nothing wrong with gazebos response or rviz. odometry and scaling as well as sim time seem to be ok.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96096/move-base-velocity-commands/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on your controller setup for move_base and might warrant deeper investigation, but here is a guess: You are hitting recovery behaviors, most likely because the local planner could never find a plan. This would hint at a problem with the costmap setup.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-10-30**:
Nothing in the status logs...but by setting the escape_vel to a none negative number. The robot stoped moving backward proving that in fact it was in a recovery mode as you say.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-12-16**:
After backing out costmap configurations going to defaults and moving to ekl combined odom with an GPS in gazebo I resolved this issue.